# Love this site? I think, too much.

Tags: bug, status-completed

"Love this site?" is too wide, it appears.

[image]

- **OS**: Windows 7
- **Browser**: Chrome Version 66.0.3359.139

Comment: Could you provide some more details? Browser, OS, etc.

Comment: I noticed this as well, with Windows 10 and Chrome, but it's now fixed.